# Want to add a google maps button to customer address form

Tags: php, mysql, google-maps

I'm looking for a way to add a google maps button to a customer contact form that pulls the customers address from MySQL

So basically I want to have a google maps button on the customer contact form that takes the address for that customer stored in MySQL and when the button is pressed it navigates to google maps and displays that customers address.

Comment: This is a bad question. You should rewrite it. I can't understand what is the problem exactly.

Comment: That would be funny, because I didn't downvote your question.

Comment: That's not hard. So? Where is the problem? Do you have some code?

Comment: @alkis I apologize I assumed since you were the only response you down voted. My bad for jumping to conclusions!

Comment: @alkis I don't have any code as I don't have a clue where to begin, I've been searching for a premade script but everything I find just add's a marker and uses latitude and longitude coordinates. I just want to take the address stored in mysql and have that linked to a google maps button on the page so when you click on it it navigates to google maps and display directions to that location

Comment: I rephrased the question

Comment: I posted an answer with what I believe is what you need. If something is missing please leave a comment

Answer (score 2):

Try this https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/52370/how-to-geocode-addresses-from-mysql-and-add-them-like-markers-to-the-google-map I don't think it is exactly what you want but it should get you going in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I've actually tried this out and it didn't do what I was looking for, it seems to just place markers. But thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I did it!
The original question was exactly what I was trying to find out...for hours and hours! Everything I found is for a much more complex implementation.

I just wanted a button that would take the address returned from the database and give the end-user the option to go to Google Maps. Couldn't find the solution anywhere.

Assuming my database has returned values to these fields:

'$loaded_street'

'$loaded_city'

'$loaded_state'

'$loaded_zip'

```
    <a href="https://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&source=s_q&hl=en&geocode=&q=<?php echo $loaded_street?>, +<?php echo $loaded_city?>,+<?php echo $loaded_state?>,+<?php echo $loaded_zip?>" data-role="button" data-ajax="false">Go to Map</a>
```

I did a property search at Google Maps, hit their "Send" button, which launched my email client and included a link to that address.
I took the address out and added the php for each field on my form and it worked!
I'm sure there's a cleaner approach, but I'm not a programmer so I was happy to get it to work since finding such a simple answer was so difficult.


No script, no map API, geocodes, longtitude and lat. Just a link with the right variables.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a scenario for you.
First of all you must know that you will have to use javascript with google maps api.
As Jason suggested you must use geocode. 
Geocode is a service of google maps, that gives you the ability to give the api an address, so it can return you something that you can use for the map, like latitude and longtitude. 
What you can do is use ajax to request from your server the address, then you use the api as I mentioned and after that is easy. If you don't want to just place a marker, just don't. When you have the location in a way that is useful to your map, you can do whatever you want. From what I understand, you want an infowindow with the address in it.

Some examples that might help you

[Geocoding example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple)

[Jquery ajax post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

[How to add an infowindow to your marker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#InfoWindows)

[Live example for infowindow](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/infowindow-simple)

**UPDATE**

I believe that, if you take the first example and change it a little bit it will do the work. In the example it takes the address from the input. What you will do, is when the user presses the button, then you make an ajax post (or get) to your server and receive the address. When you receive the address you use geocode as the example where you add an infowindow to your marker displaying what you want.

Comment: With all of the above you have all the pieces you need. Glue them together and if you get stuck, return with the code you managed and we'll find a solution.